# returnを使用した計算について

Tags: ruby

```
5.times do
    def a
        x = rand(1..10).to_f
        p "x = " << x.to_s
        return @a_result if @a_result
        @a_result = (40 + 20 + 34) / x
    end

    def b
        return @b_result if @b_result
        @b_result = a * 2
    end

    def c
        return @c_result if @c_result
        @c_result = b.to_f / 2
    end

    p a, b, c
end
```

上記のようなコードでaとbを計算した場合、5回とも同じ値になってしまいます。
return @～ が繰り返しで同じ値になってしまうのが問題なのは分かるのですがどのようにしたら良いのか分からず困っています。
上の計算くらいであれば良いのですが、もっと複雑なものになると時間が掛かるので、できる限り速く計算したいため a,b を一度求めたらその値をそのまま使い、1巡したらa,b,cの値をリセットしたいのですが、何か良い方法はあるのでしょうか。
説明が下手で申し訳ありませんが教えて頂けるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ループ処理の最初(`5.times do` の直後か `p a, b, c` の直前)に `@a_result = @b_result = @c_result = nil` を入れるとか。ところで、`x = rand(10).to_f` で `x` が `0` になる場合があって、その場合は `@a_result, @b_result, @c_result` 全てが `Infinity` になってしまいます。

Comment: 確かそうですね！そこまで考えていませんでした。訂正します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

与えられたコードですと、グローバルに(より正確には、`Object`クラスに) `a`, `b`, `c` メソッドを定義していることになり、これは、いろいろと問題が発生する可能性が高いです。

@えむけー さんが仰っているように、それ専用のクラスを用意する方が良いと思います。また、今回のような、一度だけ計算したい、ということを実現するにあたって、 ruby でよく使われるのは `||=` のオペレータだと思っています。

なので、自分がこの処理を記述するとするならば、

```
class Calculator
  def a
    @a ||=
      begin
        x = rand(10).to_f
        p "x = " << x.to_s
        (40 + 20 + 34) / x
      end
  end

  def b
    @b ||= a * 2
  end

  def c
    @c ||= b.to_f / 2
  end
end

5.times do
  calculator = Calculator.new
  calculator.instance_eval do
    p a, b, c
  end
end
```

みたいな形になると思います。

Answer (score 3):

クラスにしてしまうのがよいかなと思いました

```ruby
class A
  def a
    return @a_result if @a_result
    x = rand(10).to_f
    p "x = " << x.to_s
    @a_result = (40 + 20 + 34) / x
  end

  def b
    return @b_result if @b_result
    @b_result = a * 2
  end

  def c
    return @c_result if @c_result
    @c_result = b.to_f / 2
  end

  def print
    p a, b, c
  end
end

5.times do
  A.new.print
end
```